# No space left on 500 GB device after filled with 30 GB

Tags: hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi with an USB drive connected. The USB drive is mounted with the following entry

/etc/fstab `dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD auto noatime 0 0`

I don't know exactly what this means. But the result is that in the file explorer I get two folders under media called MULTIMEDIA, one with no content and the other folder with content. This seems wonky to me.

Now to the real problem.

I connect to the Raspberry Pi via RealVNC to copy media to the MULTIMEDIA folder. When I do that I get the message

`mv: filename: No space left on device`

Why do I get this message even if there is 450 GB free space on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re not actually accessing your external USB drive.

When your USB drive is mounted on `/media/USBHDD`, everything from `/media/USBHDD/`, and below that, is part of your USB drive. Any media data you want on your USB drive, should be copied to `/media/USBHDD/...` or a subdirectory of it.

The directory you’re copying your media files to, `/media/MULTIMEDIA/`, is not on your USB drive, but is (probably) part of your root (/) filesystem. Anything you put there, will take up space on your boot (SD) device. This explains why you have less free space there than you expect.

Use the `df` command to verify that your drive is actually mounted where you expect it to be. This command also shows the amount of free space on each mounted device.

EDIT: Make sure that `/media/USBHDD` exists. If it doesn’t, you can create it with:

`sudo mkdir /media/USBHDD`

If you don’t see your USB drive mounted with the `df` command, you 
can manually mount it with:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD`